# connect sql server in android studio by variable

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, android-studio

I am try to connect to sqlserver in android studio if  i use variavle like this:

```
String server ="192.168.1.2";
String database = "Db2020";
String user = "sa";
String password = "23457633";
```

it worked fine and conncted, put when read variavle from file like this:

```
    ReadFile readFile=new ReadFile(fileEvents);
    server=readFile.servername;
    database=readFile.database;
    user=readFile.username;
    password=readFile.password;
```

it not conncted.
i do not way?????

hear my code :

---

public class ReadFile  {

```
String servername ,username,password,database;

public ReadFile (String fileEvents) {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileEvents));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (
            IOException e) {
    }
    String result = text.toString();
    int xStart = 0, xOptin = 1;
    for (int xx = 0; xx != result.length(); xx = xx + 1) {
        if (result.substring(xx, xx + 1).equals("-")) {
            if (xOptin == 1) {
               servername = result.substring(xStart, xx -1);
            }
            if (xOptin == 2) {
                username = result.substring(xStart, xx-1);
            }
            if (xOptin == 3) {
                password = result.substring(xStart, xx-1);
            }
            if (xOptin == 4) {
                database = result.substring(xStart, xx-1);
            }
            xStart = xx + 2;
            xOptin++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

class Connectionclass:

public class Connectionclass {

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
String server ="192.168.1.2";
String database = "Db2020";
String user = "sa";
String password = "23457633";
public Connection Conn(String fileEvents){
    ReadFile readFile=new ReadFile(fileEvents);
    server=readFile.servername;
    database=readFile.database;
    user=readFile.username;
    password=readFile.password;

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Connection conn=null;
    String ConnectionURL =null;
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+server+";databaseName="+database+";user="+user+";password="+password;
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
    }catch (SQLException se){

    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){

    }catch (Exception e){}
    return conn;
}
```

}

---

public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    
    File fileEvents = new File( getFilesDir()+"/text/sample");

Connectionclass con = new Connectionclass();
conn = con.Conn(fileEvents.toString());
if (conn == null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Not Establish...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Connection Establish...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Please [reconsider using JDBC in a mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file into a big string and then parsing it again seems unnecessary.

Try something like

```
public ReadFile (String fileEvents) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileEvents));
    servername = br.ReadLine();
    username = br.ReadLine();
    password = br.ReadLine();
    database = br.ReadLine();
    br.close();
}
```